# Run codeigniter application on LAN

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, xampp

I have developed a web application in codeigniter. My server is XAMPP. I have my application in server so i am running application in server browser with the url of localhost/app_name.

My Question is how to run my application in server client machine in with IP address do i have to do any setup for this?

Comment: You also need to set the virtual hosts in your client machine with your ip address

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access your server from other machine. In that case two issue is possible.

1. If you just need to access from local network.
2. If you need to access from internet i.e. from anywhere on earth.

for 2 you would have to have real(public) IP address.

for 1: you can access only from local network. Local ip address is enough.

in both case you need to make a small change in `httpd.conf` file.

```
 #your root directory address in full 
<Directory "C:/Program Files/*/www">
 Order allow, deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Note:** After changing, you need to restart your Apache server. then you can access from outside your own machine.There is lot of answers on visiting sites on local.

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

**Step 1:**  Add IP as Listner to `httpd.conf` file of your Apache server

> ```
> Listen 80 
> Listen [your IP here]:80
> ```

**Step 2:**  Find the following code

```
<Directory "cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

and replace above code with following lines

```
<Directory "cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Thats all you need to do if you want to access site over local network.